# What effect does framerate have on mob spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Prior to 1.6 I had set the video option "limit framerate" when trying to eliminate a persistent hang problem (which finally went away when I dropped my view distance from "far" to "normal").  I also built a large (80x30) mob spawner that could go 8+ *hours* with nothing spawning inside.  In fact, often when the mob spawner would dry up I could wander through caves for hours and never have any monsters spawn at all.  With "F3 radar" I could see that nothing was spawning anywhere around me.  I suspected a bug.

In 1.6 Notch un-limited anyone who had previously limited the framerate.  Since it didn't matter I left it unlimited.  **Now my mob trap spawns mobs.**  And my typical framerate is only about 3x what the "limited" framerate was, so it's not linear.

**I was wrong**.  I had one good session in the trap (4 or 5 stacks of gunpowder in a few hours) but I parked there overnight and got absolutely zero items.

Comment: My bet is that it has nothing to do with the frame rate and was some other, unrelated bug. Try re-limiting your frame rate and see if mobs still spawn.

Comment: Try resetting the difficulty by cycling through the difficulties until it passes "peaceful" and is on "normal" again.

Comment: @Resorath I tried that many times before the update with no effect.

Comment: Try running to the next 512x512 chunk (or just run 512 blocks away), do things there for a while, and then come back.

Comment: That causes many things to spawn as I arrive... once.  When they're dead, usually nothing spawns anywhere around me for hours.

Comment: Hmm, that's really odd. [Ethoslab](http://www.youtube.com/ethoslab) (a YouTuber) has had the problem sometimes, but running to the next chunk and back fixes it for him.

Comment: I have considered making a rail system that carries me far away and then returns me to the pickup spot for a while (giant redstone delay line!) before sending me away again.

Comment: You might have made your trap wrong. Can you link to a picture of it?

Comment: F3 debug info only shows mobs within an euclidean distance of 64 blocks.

Comment: Are you very close to the mob spawner while you are waiting? You may need to make a water conveyor from your mob spawner to your camping spot.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but it came up in a Google.

It has recently been theorised (and to a certain extent proved) that there is a bug related to mobs spawning on the edge of the loaded chunk area, wandering out and still using up the mob limit.

Further analysis and experimentation is available in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MBEdG9Qj-o).

Answer (score 1):

There is no effect as far as I know. All you need is light.